# application.property values overriding all specific profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I have configured profile properties like

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:${spring.profiles.country}/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
})
```

Also, the following program arguments are given for running the service

```
-Dspring.profiles.country=australia -Dspring.profiles.active=qa
```

If same property with different values given application.property as well as US/application.QA.properties ,server will always take values from application.properties? why? How to fix this?
What I required is if a property is given in active profile it should take .

Comment: It should ideally take it from the properties file defined last in @PropertySource. This is from the documentation `In cases where a given property key exists in more than one .properties file, the last @PropertySource annotation processed will 'win' and override.`

Comment: In the @PropertySource annotation, you have mentioned the file as `US/application-QA.properties`, but in the question you mention the properties file name as `US/application.QA.properties`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Are you sure that it's reading your profile specific properties file at all?  My guess is that it's ONLY reading application.properties.

Comment: It reading both properties file ,but if same key is  given in both property file application.properties is the winner.